# remove the logs older than x days in linux

Tags: bash, date, logging

In my bash script, I want to keep logs only for x days and remove older than that. log file name itself contain the creation date.

log format:

```
tps-20170917145225514-12423.tps (17st Sept 2017)
tps-20170921134300641-2563.tps (21st Sept 2017)
```

My idea is to sort all the logs and extract time for the latest log file and then evaluate the earliest time by subtracting the x days from it something like

```
date -d "10 days"
```

Then remove all logs earlier than evaluated earliest time.

these logs are stored in different sub directories and need to remove from all locations.

Please help me if I am using correct approach or is there any better approach for this problem.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Can you just use logrotate instead? It was built for this.

Comment: these logs are copied from different locations, I dont think we can use logrotate.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to remove log files older than N days, e.g.:

```
find <dir> -type f ! -newermt '10 days ago' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: i can't use system date for two reason.
a) logs are copied from different locations so timestamp get changed and we don't have control over it.
b) logs could be old say 1 year old and we require latest x days out of them.